# Android InputManagerCompat.InputDeviceListener custom class not receiving callback on any method

Tags: android, gamepad

I have an Android application that uses a class extending the following type:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
public class GamePadController extends View implements InputManagerCompat.InputDeviceListener {
    // The current device that is controlling the ship
    private InputDevice mInputDevice;
    private int mDPadState;
    ...
```

When I run the apk in a mobile sometimes the Gamepad is captured in android and my custom methods `onGenericMotionEvent` and `onKeyUp` are called.

It is a random behaviour, sometimes my methods are called and my behaviour is executed but sometimes only the default behaviour happens (like if my classes were not registered).

Things I observed:

- In any case when I run the app it takes some time for my methods to
  be called, like if there was some lazy loading that I should force
  sooner (maybe).
- The code my changes is based on did work, but I introduced
  other things that don't look related at all (other classes, a thread)
- No exceptions or errors in the LogCat, already made sure of no empty catches and things alike

Do you have any clue or advice on this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like I was putting the callback methods in a specific View within the Activity (which had other elements like textviews), meaning that only when that specific element was focused the input was captured in the callback... that is why the documentation tells you to put the callbacks in the Activity or the View... probably it made more sense to put this behaviour in the activity so it was captured no matter what was in focus.